# Retrieve data from checkboxes in form

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, angular-material

My problem is that I have a form, and when a user submits the form, I want to receive the data which the user has submitted. This data should be wrapped in a single object. I use the formBuilder in Angular, but it seems as if it is mostly possible to retrieve data with formBuilder from `<input>` tags (quote from the top answer in [this post:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705987/use-formcontrolname-with-something-like-span) *"formControlName only works on input, select and textarea. anything that has "value" property."*

I have defined a form within my constructor and initialized fields, making use of the formBuilder;

*component.ts*

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
) {
  this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    selectedAccount: '',
    selectedContactInfo: '',
  });
}
```

In my html, I have two places where a user should choose something from; a dropdown-menu and a selection of checkboxes. `selectedAccount` from my constructor is applied to `<mat-select>`, which works fine; on submission of form, I can see which account I chose. However, it seems that I can't apply `formControlName="selectedContactInfo"` to the `div` in checkboxes area; it returns empty string.

*component.html*

```
<!-- DROPDOWN - WORKS PERFECT -->
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>CHOOSE ACCOUNT</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="selectedAccount">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let account of accounts" [value]="account.name">{{account.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<!-- CHECKBOXES - DOESN'T RETRIEVE DATA WHEN FORM IS SUBMITTED -->
h2 class="mat-h2">CHOOSE TELEPHONE NUMBERS WE CAN CONTACT YOU ON</h2>
<div formControlName="selectedContactInfo" class="item-container">
  <mat-checkbox>{{contactInfo.privateMobile}}</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox>{{contactInfo.workMobile}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

From the checkboxes, I want to retrieve the actual data. So if the first checkbox has been checked, I want to receive whatever data that `contactInfo.privateMobile` contains, probably a string or int of 8 digits, and assign it to `selectedContactInfo` in the constructor, in the very same manner I did for `selectedAccount` and the dropdown menu.

I want `selectedContactInfo` to contain the data for the checkboxes; if both are checked, it returns the mobile numbers for both. If one is checked, it returns that number etc. I also tried with `selectedContactInfo: []` in constructor since it needs to return data for all checkboxes, but that just returns null right now.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit*: For reference (if anyone wants to know this), this is how I check the data when I submit my form to see if it contains right info. Dont know if its relevant:

```
onSubmit(userData) {
  console.log(userData);
}
```

Comment: Please create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) example with some sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this example

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="rememberLogin"> Remember login
    </form>
    <p>Form value: {{ form.value | json }}</p>  
    <!-- {rememberLogin: true } -->
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        rememberLogin: [true]
    });
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The `console.log` just returns a boolean of whether the box has been clicked in real-time. I want the value, "Check me!", to be submitted together with other elements of the form in a single object as a part of the formBuilder.group - that is, assign it to `selectedContactInfo` or other variables initialized there. Using this approach, I could just as well disband the formBuilder.

Comment: you want to use form builder to get value in checkbox?

Comment: Yes, in the same manner that I used the form builder to get the value for the dropdown menu. I edited my original post of what I want to receive from checkboxes (right under the code of component.html)

Comment: please check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927167/angular-reactiveforms-producing-an-array-of-checkbox-values) similar answer and also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000307/angular-5-reactive-form-set-mat-checkbox-to-check)

Comment: i have also updated my answer with input type="checkbox" if the given link not helpful then try given example

Comment: thank you very much for the help! i was AFK, will check out all the links now and return with answer when I tried them out

Comment: Seems its impossible to extract the value from a `<mat-checkbox>`. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

The output you want is an array of numbers while the selection will return `true` or `false` since it is a checkbox. In situations like this where the form contains different values from what you desire, you can use `valueChanges` to detect the changes in a particular `FormControl` and extract the desired result from the `FormControl` or `FormArray`.

#### Solution

Since you want an array, the first thing you need to do is create a `FormArray` for `selectedContactInfo`.

```js
contactInfo = {
    privateMobile: 1800124152,
    workMobile: 1800124124
};

this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    selectedAccount: '',
    selectedContactInfo: this.formBuilder.array(Object.keys(this.contactInfo).map(key => false))
});
```

Note that we are initializing the `FormArray` using `contactInfo`. This will basically get the keys from the object and create an array of the same length with `false` values (since initially the checkbox values are `false`). Of course, if you need it to be checked by default, you will need to map the selection to the checkboxes but for the sake of this example, we will start with all `false` values.

**Registering the FormArray in the template**

Set the [`FormArrayName`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName) in the template so we access the `true`/`false` values from the checkbox. Use the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) since we are iterating over `contactInfo` which is an object.

```html
<div class="item-container" formArrayName="selectedContactInfo">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let contactNumber of contactInfo | keyvalue; let i = index">
        <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="i">{{contactNumber.value}}</mat-checkbox>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

**Map the FormArray in valueChanges**

Now, `selectContactInfo` will be an array of `true`/`false` values according to the selection of the checkboxes. This is not what we desire though, so we will subscribe to `valueChanges` and map the data to `contactInfo` and store it in a variable called `selectedContactInfo` (Note that this is different from the `FormArray`).

```js
const control = this.checkoutForm.controls.selectedContactInfo;
this.subscription = control.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.selectedContactInfo = Object.keys(this.contactInfo).map((contactNo, index) => 
        control.value[index] ? this.contactInfo[contactNo] : null
    )
    .filter(contactNo => !!contactNo);
});
```

What we are doing here is basically getting the `true`/`false` array from the `FormArray` and then mapping it to `contactInfo`. If the checkbox value is `true`, return the number, else return `null`. Then use a `filter` to filter out the `null` values.

Don't forget to unsubscribe from the `valueChanges` subscription.

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

#### [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-form-array)

Comment: Hey nash, thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer, I appreciate it a lot! I will report back when Ive tried this tomorrow! However, I hope this works for me too, since you instantiate contactInfo with numbers, while I populate the checkbox values from a REST service. I will accept your answer if it works!

Comment: Anytime :) The REST service shouldn't make a difference if it's the same as the sample data I've used. If you need more clarity I just answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927167/angular-reactiveforms-producing-an-array-of-checkbox-values) after seeing the link provided by @WaqarAli in the comments in his answer. I didn't find a satisfactory answer to that question so I provided my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261847/9739129) there. I've also used an array of objects there as it seems like a better structure and is easier to work with than objects.

Comment: I have also directly modified the `FormArray` in that example unlike here where I used a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't returns data, because you need to add formControlName for the checkbox itself, you can't add it to divs. Just add two contact infos and then you use those that have values, or you can just remove the empty one from the object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have already tried that. That doesn't work, because It only returns a boolean value of whether the checkbox has been checked or not.